# Bitrix БУС и Test-driven development TDD с PHPUnit

Tags: битрикс, phpunit, test-driven-development

Ознакомился с теорией TDD, практики как таковой нет, кроме небольшой синтетики.
Дык вот сразу встал вопрос, а как собственно применять TDD в БУСе?
Как протестировать компонент?
Получается нужно делать класс, отдельный от компонента, и его скармливать PHPUnit'у? И потом его увязывать с компонентом?

Answer (score 1):

Тестируют php-классы. Для каждого класса создаётся тестовый класс, который запускается phpunit. Задача тестового класса - проверить все функции тестируемого. Всё, что не относится к тестируемому классу - имитируется с помощью mock.